# How does a web session remain consistent when changing connection?

Tags: mobile, web, wifi, 3g

When browsing on a mobile device, it is possible to change multiple times between a 3G and WiFi connection, with associated IP address change.

How does a website maintain a user's session when their connection changes, as it would appear to be a new connection to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user session is based on a random code.

The code is send by the browser to the website as an identifier.

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID)